# Radixx Api Integration

Tags: api, testflight, sabre, radix, booking.com-api

I have been given with the credentials and  endpoint from Radixx but when I used to use the endpoint to get security token . I am getting this error :
Additional Source Information: ERR9999: Unexpected error in GetSecurityGUID.Error Generation Source Location: DSAIXUAT1APP01 Session ID: -1 Error Details: Your user ID and Password combination did not validate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Its not about code. its about headers or other info required for the same. as I was using it in soap UI tool and its showing wrong credentials. however i checked it many times that credentials are right. so I need to know if i am using wrong headers or missing header or something for the same.